# react native clear content from nested textbox after user submit

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a react native application which gives users news feeds. Againist each news feed users can choose to comment in a textbox that comes along with each news feed.
I'm able to submit it correctly but the issue is, after its been submitted, the text still remains in the textbox and also when a user starts typing against one textbox all the submit buttons for the feeds becomes active but it should only activate against the current feed in such its textbox is being typed in

CONTAINER

```
    commentPost = async (item) => {
          const togglePostCommentLoader = (item, loaderStatus) => this.state.posts.map(post => post.id === item.id ? {...post, commentPostLoader: loaderStatus } : post);
          const { userId, communityId, groupId, comment, posts: oldPosts } = this.state;
        try {
            this.setState( { posts: togglePostCommentLoader(item, true) });
            const data = await API.commentPost(communityId, groupId, userId, item.id, comment);
            this.setState({
                posts: togglePostCommentLoader(item, false),
                comment: ''
            });
        }catch(error){
    }
          this.callAfterCommentSnackBar();
        }

  render() {
    const {posts, modalVisible, showLoader, showArchiveSnackBar, showAfterCommentSnackBar, commentPostLoader, groupId, communityId, userId} = this.state;
    return (

    <GroupPostsScreen
        posts = {posts}
        navigation = {this.props.navigation}
        visible = {modalVisible}
        showLoader = {showLoader}
        showArchiveSnackBar = {showArchiveSnackBar}
        showAfterCommentSnackBar = {showAfterCommentSnackBar}
        onCallArchiveSnackBar = {this.callArchiveSnackBar}
        onCommentPost = {this.commentPost}
        commentPostLoader = {commentPostLoader}
        onSetComment = {this.setComment}
        commentValue = {this.state.comment}

        userId = {userId}
    />
    );
  }
```

TEXBOX FUNCTION TO SET STATE (ALSO IN CONTAINER)

```
  setComment= (comment) => {
    this.setState({ comment: comment })
    }
```

VIEW SCREEN

```
  <ScrollView >
  {
    posts.map((item, i) => {
      const isEnabled = commentValue[i] &&  commentValue[i].length > 0;
  return (
  <View key={i} style={styles.user}>

  <Card
  containerStyle={{borderRadius:7}}
  >
   <ListItem
    onPress={()=>(navigation.navigate('PostComments',{'postId':item.id, 
                                                      'communityId': communityId,
                                                      'communityMemberId': userId,
                                                      'groupId':groupId, 
                                                      'post':item.text}))}

    chevron={{ color: '#36a' }}
    bottomDivider = {true}
    title={item.headline}
    titleStyle={{color: '#36c', fontWeight:'500'}}
    />
    <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize:16, color:'#778899'}}>
    {item.text}
  </Text>

  <TextInput
       onChangeText={onSetComment} 
        label='Write Comment'
        underlineColor="#36a"
        // value={commentValue}
        style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', width:'90%'}}
      />

  <View style={{alignSelf:"flex-end", position:'relative', right:0,top:-20}}>
  <Icon
   disabled={!isEnabled}
   iconStyle={[(isEnabled=== true) ? styles.likedColor : styles.unLikedColor]}
    name='md-arrow-round-forward'
    type='ionicon'
    color='#999'
    onPress={() => {onCommentPost(item)}}
  />



      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <ActivityIndicator 
                animating={item.commentPostLoader===true}
                size="small"
              />
      </View>

      </View>


    </Card>

  </View>
      );
    })
  }


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Uncomment `// value={commentValue}` inside `VIEW SCREEN`

2) Make sure that `commentPost` inside `CONTAINER` doesn't throw an error

New suggested solution:

CONTAINER

```js
commentPost = async(item) => {
  const togglePostCommentLoader = (item, loaderStatus) => this.state.posts.map(post => post.id === item.id ? { ...post,
    commentPostLoader: loaderStatus
  } : post);
  const {
    userId,
    communityId,
    groupId,
    comments,
    posts: oldPosts
  } = this.state;
  try {
    this.setState({
      posts: togglePostCommentLoader(item, true)
    });
    const data = await API.commentPost(communityId, groupId, userId, item.id, comment);
    this.setState({
      posts: togglePostCommentLoader(item, false),
      comments: {...comments, [item.id]: '' }
    });
  } catch (error) {}
  this.callAfterCommentSnackBar();
}

render() {
  const {
    posts,
    modalVisible,
    showLoader,
    showArchiveSnackBar,
    showAfterCommentSnackBar,
    commentPostLoader,
    groupId,
    communityId,
    userId
  } = this.state;
  return (

    <
    GroupPostsScreen posts = {
      posts
    }
    navigation = {
      this.props.navigation
    }
    visible = {
      modalVisible
    }
    showLoader = {
      showLoader
    }
    showArchiveSnackBar = {
      showArchiveSnackBar
    }
    showAfterCommentSnackBar = {
      showAfterCommentSnackBar
    }
    onCallArchiveSnackBar = {
      this.callArchiveSnackBar
    }
    onCommentPost = {
      this.commentPost
    }
    commentPostLoader = {
      commentPostLoader
    }
    onSetComment = {
      this.setComment
    }
    commentValues = {
      this.state.comments
    }

    userId = {
      userId
    }
    />
  );
}
```

TEXBOX FUNCTION TO SET STATE (ALSO IN CONTAINER)

```js
setComment= (postId) => (comment) => {
  this.setState({
    comments: {
      ...this.state.comments,
      [postId]: comment
    }
  })
}
```

VIEW SCREEN

```js
<ScrollView >
  {
    posts.map((item, i) => {
      const isEnabled = commentValue[i] &&  commentValue[i].length > 0;
  return (
  <View key={i} style={styles.user}>

  <Card
  containerStyle={{borderRadius:7}}
  >
   <ListItem
    onPress={()=>(navigation.navigate('PostComments',{'postId':item.id, 
                                                      'communityId': communityId,
                                                      'communityMemberId': userId,
                                                      'groupId':groupId, 
                                                      'post':item.text}))}

    chevron={{ color: '#36a' }}
    bottomDivider = {true}
    title={item.headline}
    titleStyle={{color: '#36c', fontWeight:'500'}}
    />
    <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize:16, color:'#778899'}}>
    {item.text}
  </Text>

  <TextInput
       onChangeText={onSetComment(item.id)} 
        label='Write Comment'
        underlineColor="#36a"
        value={commentValues[item.id]}
        style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', width:'90%'}}
      />

  <View style={{alignSelf:"flex-end", position:'relative', right:0,top:-20}}>
  <Icon
   disabled={!isEnabled}
   iconStyle={[(isEnabled=== true) ? styles.likedColor : styles.unLikedColor]}
    name='md-arrow-round-forward'
    type='ionicon'
    color='#999'
    onPress={() => {onCommentPost(item)}}
  />
      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <ActivityIndicator 
                animating={item.commentPostLoader===true}
                size="small"
              />
      </View>
      </View>
    </Card>
  </View>
      );
    })
  }


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: when i uncomment value={commentValue} it works perfectly, but when i start typing the value appears on all the textboxes for each feed

Comment: I suggest u to use:
`state = { comments: { [postId]: value } }` and `setComment= (postId) => (comment) => 
 this.setState({ comments: { ...this.state.comments, [postId]: comment } })`